# Laravel: group results by date

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my Laravel project, I have a `Match` model which contains the following fields: `id` and `starting_at` timestamp.

I would like to list all matches and group them by date, just like this:

> 1st of June:
>
> 1. Match id 57
> 2. Match id 87
>
> 2nd of June:
>
> 1. Match id 40
> 2. Match id 99
>
> ...

Thanks !

Comment: Look [here](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return a collection and then group items by `starting_at`:

```
$matches = Match::all(); // or whatever constraints you want to apply
$matchesByDate = $matches->groupBy('starting_at');
```

Mind that SQL timestamp is not a valid array key, so if `starting_at` is such a field, then you need to change it a bit, for example:

```
$matchesByDate = $matches->groupBy(function ($match) { return substr($match->starting_at, 0, 10);});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not tested but should work....also you should probably split this up into a one to many relationship that would make this much easier.

```
  $matches = Matches::select('starting_at')->distinct()->get();
    foreach($matches as $match){
      echo $match->starting_at."<br/>";
      $ids =  Matches::where("starting_at",$match->starting_at)->lists('id');
      $count = 1;
      foreach ($ids as $id){
         echo $count.". Match id ".$id."<br/>";
         $count ++;
      }
   }
```